# Library website navigation bar has hover issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website for my local library and wanted to seek some help on fixing the navigation bar. If you hover over the navigation bar the menu appears but the issues are:

- After removing mouse from nav bar sometimes the menu still displays
- The hover function on the nav bar it is sometimes sensitive but at other times delayed. Meaning that when hovering over each option it is other quick to respond and other times it is not.
- At times after hovering over the nav bar and then moving away from it the menu will still appear even though the mouse is not on the navigation. I have listed the section of HTMl code for the first dropdown in the nav bar. I have also included a link to the javascript that should be controlling the nav bar, http://p9cdn3static.sharpschool.com/javascript/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js. The website was built using a CMS. If anyone could assist with helping me resolve the issue that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

---

**Navigation Bar**
MENU

**Books & More**
Books & More

**Catalog**

Catalog

  NEW Catalog Encore

**More Books**

More Books

  Career Center Books
  title="Local Author Books">Local Author Books

  title="Books & Authors">Books & Authors

  title="Series Fiction">Series Fiction

  title="Readers Corner">Readers Corner

**Suggest a Purchase**

Suggest a Purchase

  title="Recommend Library Matericals">Recommend Library Matericals

**What’s New in Print**

What's New in Print

  title="Teen Graphic Novels">Teen Graphic Novels

  title="Fiction">Fiction

  title="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction

  title="Genealogy">GenealogyChildren's Fiction

  title="Children's Non-Fiction">Children's Non-Fiction

  title="Teen Fiction">Teen Fiction

**What’s New Listen or Watch**
What's New Listen or Watch

  title="DVDs Movies, TV & More">DVDs Movies, TV & More

  title="CD Audio Books">CD Audio Books

---

Williamson County Library: http://lib.williamson-tn.org/

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and post a [mcve]

Comment: By seeing your website, just write .focusOut() event on the dropdown menu list, So when ever cursor go out from the menu list it will hide.